# How to strip all local symbol names from executable using Clang in macOS?

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, llvm

> How to strip all local symbol names from executable in macOS?

I want to remove all local symbols from my executable, so that `nm` cannot display any function names defined by the executable etc.

I cannot use the linker `-s` switch:

```
$ gcc -fno-stack-protector myprog.c -Wl,-no_pie -Wl,-s -o myprog
ld: warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignored
```

Using `strip -x` to remove all local symbols doesn't remove the symbols.

How can I remove all local symbols, so that functions names like `_decrypt_username` doesn't show up?

```
$ nm crackme0x0 -extern-only
                 U ___stdinp
                 U ___strncpy_chk
0000000100000000 A __mh_execute_header
0000000100001750 T _crash
0000000100001710 T _decrypt_username
                 U _exit
                 U _fgets
                 U _free
00000001000018b0 T _get_vault_contents
                 U _getpass
0000000100002190 D _invalid_password_str
                 U _isxdigit
0000000100001af0 T _main
                 U _malloc
                 U _printf
                 U _rand
00000001000013b0 T _rot13
00000001000021aa D _secret_stored_for_user_str
                 U _sleep
                 U _srand
                 U _strcmp
                 U _strdup
                 U _strlen
                 U _strncmp
                 U _strtol
                 U _time
00000001000020a0 D _user_vaults
0000000100001a40 T _validate_password
0000000100001570 T _xor_with_fixed_key
0000000100001500 T _xor_with_sliding_byte_key
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Comment: Removing the names of the symbols that your code imports in order to function? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Looks like you're using gcc, not clang?

Comment: Use `strip`, without `-x`. Note that, if your program uses dynamic linking, symbols involved in dynamic linking will not be stripped, as they are needed for execution. But names of your own routines, such as `_decrypt_username`, will be stripped. Also, FYI, stripping an executable and otherwise obscuring it is insufficient to protect encryptions and decryptions from attack.

Comment: @AndyG: Default installation of Apple developer tools provides a Clang substitution for the `gcc` command.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - what is the reasoning for removing the `-s` symbol from `ld`, so that developers must use another tool (`strip`)? It seems unintuitive. However, `strip myprog` works, thank you! I see now that is has the same functionality as `ld -s`, if no "dynamic link editor" is used? What is that?

Comment: @Shuzheng: Dynamic linking is when libraries are linked into a running program, instead of into the executable file. It enables sharing libraries (all running programs on a system could share one library), updating libraries without relinking all programs, and other features. Symbols used in dynamic linking cannot be stripped because the program needs them to complete linking. I do not have a full history on removal of the `-s` option. You might also look into the `ld` options `-x`, `-non_global_symbols_strip_list` and `-non_global_symbols_no_strip_list`.

Comment: Yes, I know dynamic linking. But `strip` without any options just removes my own defined symbols for functions etc. - it doesn't remove external symbols used for dynamic linking (e.g. `printf`). So, I guess `ld -s` would be safe to use in practice? Do you know what the "dynamic link editor" is?

Comment: All your function names are marked with `T`, indicating that they are globally visible names. If you want them hidden, make the functions `static` (then they'll be marked `t` instead of `T`). Then maybe the `strip` program can remove them. IMO, it is a good idea to make functions `static` by default, only removing `static` when (a) there's a need to call it from another source file and (b) there's a header declaring the function that is used in both source files.  Sadly, C uses the `extern` by default — functions and file scope variables are global (visible outside the source file) by default.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - is there a way to make the compiler make functions static by default?

Comment: No; there isn’t a way to make functions static by default. Simply discipline yourself to write the `static` unless you know the function will be used elsewhere (and you’ve got the header to declare it in).

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked some time ago. I needed to do it in Xcode 14. To do it there one needs to set `Deployment Postprocessing` to true for a release configuration in the project settings. That will remove private symbols from the binary file. ([Here](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=macos-programming-xcode-build-schemes-diagnose-memory-corruption-and-crashes#dbg_w_crash_log)'s the source.) Keep in mind that that setting is not set by default.